# QGIS - best fit to the sectoral terrain (SRTM 30m resolution data)

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I need a help to find out the Slope of "best fit to the sectoral terrain". 
here is in details  about the area of calculation.

we have a reference point, from the reference point our sectoral area could be around 1000m with the sector range starts from 220 degree to 300 degree. I wanted to calculate the "best fit to the sectoral area between 220 degree to 300 degree with the length of 1000m".

What I did so far is, I calculated the slope of the whole terrain but I am not able to limit the slope area within 1000m with 220deg to 300degree. Again I don't know how to calculate the "best fit" of the slope for the sectoral plane.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some ideas that should get you closer to a solution.
First, given a reference point with location (x,y), then the points on the circle of radius 1000 m, at angles theta1 and theta2 will have coordinates:

```
x1 = x + 1000*sin(theta1)
y1 = y + 1000*cos(theta1)
x2 = x + 1000*sin(theta2)
y2 = y + 1000*cos(theta2)
```

With the three points (x,y) (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) you should be able to create the "pie slice" of your sector. In GRASS-GIS, for example, you can write a 5 line text file in standard vector format, and use it as input to the `v.in.ascii` module (see  [man page](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/v.in.ascii.html)).

Now convert that triangular polygon to a raster:

```
v.to.rast triangle output=triangle type=area
```

and create a new elevation raster of just the "pie slice" by using this triangle as a mask:

```
r.mask triangle
r.mapcalc sector_elev = elevation
```

Now, for the "best fit": I would export all the elevation values from the sector_elev raster and use any of the options available for doing scatter plots to plot the elevations vs the number of cells with each elevation (probability density function), and fit a line to the scatter plot. This could be in a spreadsheet program, Matlab, or similar.

HTH